# Use Chernoff bound to prove Hoeffding bound

Tags: inequality

Let $X = \sum_{I=1}^n X_i$, where $X_i$s' are independent variables with $0\leq X_i \leq 1$, and $\mu = E(X)$. Given Chernoff bounds: for any $\delta \geq 0$, $Pr(X \geq (1+\delta)\mu) ~\leq~ e^{- \min\{\delta,\delta^2\} \mu/3}$
and $Pr(X \leq (1-\delta)\mu ) ~\leq~ e^{- \delta^2 \mu/3}$, we want to prove a loose Hoeffding bound: for any $t\geq 0$, $Pr(| X - \mu | \geq t)
    ~\leq~ 2 \exp( - t^2/3n ).$

I claimed that $\mu \leq n$, and decomposed $Pr(|X-\mu|\geq t)\leq Pr (X \geq \mu + t) + Pr(\mu\geq X + t)$. The second term is easy to see, but for the first term, I simplified it to $P({X - \mu\geq t}) \leq \exp(-\min\{t, \frac{t^2}{\mu}\}/3)$, and let $t\leq \frac{t^2}{\mu}$, which is $\mu\leq t$, I couldn't deduce more since I couldn't assume $t$ is larger or $n$ is larger. Any hint to prove it?